# Merge the files into a new big file until the number of user id's become 10 Million

Tags: java, file, linkedhashset

I have around 100 files in a folder. Each file will have data like this and each line resembles an user id.

```
960904056
6624084
1096552020
750160020
1776024
211592064
1044872088
166720020
1098616092
551384052
113184096
136704072
```

And I am trying to keep on merging the files from that folder into a new big file until the total number of user id's become 10 Million in that new big file.

I am able to read all the files from a particular folder and then I keep on adding the user id's from those files in a linkedhashset. And then I was thinking to see whether the size of hashset is 10 Million and if it is 10 million then write all those user id's to a new text file. Is that feasoible solution?

That 10 million number should be configurable. In future, If I need to change that 10 million 1o 50Million
then I should be able to do that.

Below is the code I have so far

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    File folder = new File("C:\\userids-20130501");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    Set<String> userIdSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file = listOfFiles[i];
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            try {
                List<String> content = FileUtils.readLines(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                userIdSet.addAll(content);
                if(userIdSet.size() >= 10Million) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(userIdSet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated on this? And any better way to do the same process?

Comment: Do you want to stop after you cross your upper limit? Or want to stop exactly at? And why not write at the same time of reading?

Comment: As soon as I cross the upper limit or exactly at same point both are fine with me.

Comment: Then why now read a line from input file and write in output at same time, and increasing counter?

Comment: Do you mean like `sort -u *.txt | head -10000000 > out.txt`?

Comment: Yes kind of but I need to do in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from where we left. ;)

You can use the `FileUtils` to write the file along with the `writeLines()` method.

Try this -

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

File folder = new File("C:\\userids-20130501");

Set<String> userIdSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
int count = 1;
for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
        try {
            List<String> content = FileUtils.readLines(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            userIdSet.addAll(content);
            if(userIdSet.size() >= 10Million) {
                File bigFile = new File("<path>" + count + ".txt");
                FileUtils.writeLines(bigFile, userIdSet);
                count++;
                userIdSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If the purpose of saving the data in the `LinkedHashSet` is just for writing it again to another file then I have another solution.

**EDIT to avoid OutOfMemory exception**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
File folder = new File("C:\\userids-20130501");

int fileNameCount = 1;
int contentCounter = 1;
File bigFile = new File("<path>" + fileNameCount + ".txt");
boolean isFileRequired = true;
for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
        try {
            List<String> content = FileUtils.readLines(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            contentCounter += content.size();
            if(contentCounter < 10Million) {
                FileUtils.writeLines(bigFile, content, true);
            } else {
                fileNameCount++;
                bigFile = new File("<path>" + fileNameCount + ".txt");
                FileUtils.writeLines(bigFile, content);
                contentCounter = 1;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to get run out of memory by storing it into LinkedHashSet. is there any better solution?

Comment: Wrote a new method to avoid going out of memory.

Comment: What is count here Junaid?

Comment: One more quick thing, path will always be same at both of the two place you mentioned above? Right?

Comment: Yup. Thats the path where your merged big file with 10 million records will be created and stored.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32044/discussion-between-techgeeky-and-junaid)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of the Set as intermediate storage if you write at the same time that you read from file. You could do something like this,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class AppMain {
  private static final int NUMBER_REGISTERS = 10000000;

  private static String[] filePaths = {"filePath1", "filePaht2", "filePathN"}; 
  private static String mergedFile = "mergedFile";


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    mergeFiles(filePaths, mergedFile);
  }

  private static void mergeFiles(String[] filePaths, String mergedFile) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader[] readerArray = createReaderArray(filePaths);
    boolean[] closedReaderFlag = new boolean[readerArray.length];

    PrintWriter writer = createWriter(mergedFile);

    int currentReaderIndex = 0;
    int numberLinesInMergedFile = 0;

    BufferedReader currentReader = null;
    String currentLine = null;
    while(numberLinesInMergedFile < NUMBER_REGISTERS && getNumberReaderClosed(closedReaderFlag) < readerArray.length){
      currentReaderIndex = (currentReaderIndex + 1) % readerArray.length; 

      if(closedReaderFlag[currentReaderIndex]){
       continue;
      }

      currentReader = readerArray[currentReaderIndex];

      currentLine = currentReader.readLine();
      if(currentLine == null){
       currentReader.close();
       closedReaderFlag[currentReaderIndex] = true;
       continue;
      }

      writer.println(currentLine);
      numberLinesInMergedFile++;
    }

    writer.close();
    for(int index = 0; index < readerArray.length; index++){
      if(!closedReaderFlag[index]){
       readerArray[index].close();
      }
    }

  }

  private static BufferedReader[] createReaderArray(String[] filePaths) throws FileNotFoundException{
    BufferedReader[] readerArray = new BufferedReader[filePaths.length];

    for (int index = 0; index < readerArray.length; index++) {
      readerArray[index] = createReader(filePaths[index]);
    }

    return readerArray;
  }

  private static BufferedReader createReader(String path) throws FileNotFoundException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

    return reader;
  }

  private static PrintWriter createWriter(String path) throws FileNotFoundException{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path);

    return writer;
  }

  private static int getNumberReaderClosed(boolean[] closedReaderFlag){
    int count = 0;

    for (boolean currentFlag : closedReaderFlag) {
      if(currentFlag){
    count++;
      }
    }

    return count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're going, you likely may run out of memory, your are keeping an unnecessary record in **userIdSet**.

A slight modification that can improve your code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    File folder = new File("C:\\userids-20130501");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    // there's no need for the userIdSet!
    //Set<String> userIdSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

    // Instead I'd go for a counter ;)
    long userIdCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file = listOfFiles[i];
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            try {
                List<String> content = FileUtils.readLines(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                // I just want to know how many lines there are...
                userIdCount += content.size();

                // my guess is you'd probably want to print what you've got
                // before a possible break?? - You know better!
                System.out.println(content);

                if(userIdCount >= 10Million) {
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Like I noted, just a slight modification. It was not my intention to run a very detailed analysis on your code. I just pointed out a glaring mis-design.

Finally, where you stated **System.out.println(content);**, you might consider writing to file at that point.

If you will write to file one line at a time, you try-catch block may look like this:

```
try {
    List<String> content = FileUtils.readLines(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    for(int lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < content.size(); lineNumber++){
        if(++userIdCount >= 10Million){
           break;
        }
        // here, write to file... But I will use simple System.out.print for example
        System.out.println(content.get(lineNumber));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your code can be improved in many ways, but I don't have time to do that. But I hope my suggestion can push you further to the front in the right track. Cheers!